# IOS: How to make the subview that was loaded from nib file can use it's button (IBAction)

Tags: ios, subviews

I used the following method to add subviews to the superview, but when I add a IBAction UIButton to the subview, run the app, and click the button from subview, the app crashed, and I don't know why, and how to solve this problem.?!

```
CGFloat yOrigin = i* self.view.frame.size.width;
    Home *newView = [[Home alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home" bundle:nil];
    newView.view.frame = CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [scroll addSubview:[newView view]];
    [newView release];
```

P.S.
I use the nib file because of the convinience of the designing UI and functions. (MVC?)

Comment: BTW, the subview is adding to a UIScrollView instance.

Comment: It will help your cause if you include the crash logs in the question.

Answer (score 0):

because the viewController is responsible to handle the view components actions and outlets this is cant be done by the view itself .. try to presentModelViewController instead of adding subView and it should work.

Comment: I wanna add it to UIScrollView, but presentModelViewController method is just for UIViewController? BTW, did you mentiond the method called presentModalViewController, not presentModelViewController?

Comment: yes its Modal not Model this my mistake .. so why you are loading the scrollView from nib file ? create it programmatically and add it as subview.